# Recursion is not preserving values in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, binary-tree, callstack

I am currently trying to solve this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Here is my code:

```
function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
    this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
    this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
    this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 }
 
 const NINE = new TreeNode(9);
 const FIFTEEN = new TreeNode(15);
 const SEVEN = new TreeNode(7);
 const TWENTY = new TreeNode(20, FIFTEEN, SEVEN);
 const THREE = new TreeNode(3, NINE, TWENTY);


var maxDepth = function(root) {
    let max = 0;
    helper(root, max, 0);
    console.log(max, 'max')
    return max + 1;
};

function helper(root, max, i) {
    if(root === null) return max;
    if(max < i) {
        max = i;
     }
    
     const maxLeft = helper(root.left, max, i+1); 
     const maxRight = helper(root.right, max, i+1);
    
    return max = maxLeft > maxRight ? maxLeft : maxRight;
}

maxDepth(THREE);
```

With that, I have 3 questions:

1)
I don't understand this particular line:

```
return max = maxLeft > maxRight ? maxLeft : maxRight; //2
```

Here, wouldn't the `max` value in the `maxDepth` function also update? In this case, I think it should be `2`. However, when I console.logged it in the original function, I received `0` as a result. Why is this happening and how can I preserve that maximum value as returned from the callstack?

2. Originally I wrote these 2 lines below:

```
const maxLeft = helper(root.left, max, i+1); 
const maxRight = helper(root.right, max, i+1);
```

as:

```
helper(root.left, max, i+1); 
helper(root.right, max, i+1);
```

Because my logic is after this condition here:

```
if(max < i) {
   max = i;
}
```

However, it seems like as the function returns up to the call stack, `max` is being set back to 0. Why isn't the value of `max` being preserved, and how do we preserve that value?

3. I'm still confused about the 2 lines above:

```
const maxLeft = helper(root.left, max, i+1); //1
const maxRight = helper(root.right, max, i+1); //2
```

Here, the values of `maxLeft` and `maxRight` are preserved as `1` and `2`. Why weren't they being set back to `0` as we return up the call stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a number to a function and change it within the function, it is only changed within that function -

```js
var maxDepth = function(root) {
    let max = 0;            // define a number, max
    helper(root, max, 0);   // call helper with root, max, and 0
    console.log(max, 'max') // max will always be 0, helper cannot change it
    return max + 1;         // this will always be 0 + 1
};
```

See in `helper` below it has a `return` statement? That means a *new* value is coming out. In the code above, you don't do anything with it. It is simply discarded and execution moves onto the next line -

```js
function helper(root, max, i) {
    if(root === null) return max;
    if(max < i) {
        max = i;
     }
    
     const maxLeft = helper(root.left, max, i+1); 
     const maxRight = helper(root.right, max, i+1);
    
    return max = maxLeft > maxRight ? maxLeft : maxRight; // <-
}
```

So you can update `max` by reassigning it inside `maxDepth` -

```js
var maxDepth = function(root) {
    let max = 0;
    max = helper(root, max, 0); // <- get new max from helper
    console.log(max, 'max')
    return max + 1;
};
```

This might fix some of your misunderstanding but it sadly it doesn't fix the code. Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

```js
const empty =
  {}
 
const node = (val, left = empty, right = empty) =>
  ({ val, left, right })

function max(a, b)
{ if (a > b)
    return a
  else
    return b
}
 
function depth(t)
{ if (t === empty)
    return 0
  else
    return 1 + max(depth(t.left), depth(t.right))
}

const mytree = 
  node(3, node(9), node(20, node(15), node(7)))
  
console.log(depth(mytree))
// 3
```